# How can I write a newline char in an alias definition?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias

in my `~/.bash_aliases` file
there is:  `msr='sed :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ "\/home"/" \/there"\n/g'`

It is used as an example, where I have to put newlines in the aliases. How can I make that?

I get the error as below:

> syntax err near unexpected token newline

Comment: I don't think newlines are the problem here in particular. You need to escape the `sed` command like this:  `alias msr='sed '\'':a;N...'\'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a function instead of an alias trivially bypasses this problem, and generally a whole bunch of similar problems.

```
msr () {
    sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ "\/home"/" \/there"
/g' "$@"
}
```

There is usually no reason to prefer an alias over a function.

Comment: There is one extra slash (which has obviously nothing to do with the good suggestion to use a function instead as `sed` in `alias` gets ugly). Also, is there a reason to use `\n` once and then do a literal `<newline>`?

Comment: I'm not sure where the OP wanted literal newlines or literal slashes. Inspired guesses and gifted mindreading more than welcome.